# How to configure existing raid after upgrading to 14.04 from 11

Tags: partitioning, raid

I have a pci raid controller, with two 250G drives.  Configured this to work on ubuntu 11 a few years back.  Have since forgotten much about the details of this configuration (i.e. software, hardware, raid type) and have recently installed 14.04.  On my 11 installation, I had a 500G mount.  I'm guessing it was raid0 or some other software configuration of the 2 disks.

How can I get this existing pair of raid disks working again without erasing any of the data?

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 164.7 GB, 164696555520 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 20023 cylinders, total 321672960 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00045ec8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   315906047   157952000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       315908094   321671167     2881537    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       315908096   321671167     2881536   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005a448

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1           16065   625137344   312560640   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 251.0 GB, 251000193024 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30515 cylinders, total 490234752 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00003bda

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1           16065   980463014   490223475   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdd: 251.0 GB, 251000193024 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30515 cylinders, total 490234752 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdd doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on `dmraid`.  The following got my lvm back. Apparently I had an existing LVM?

```
sudo dmraid -ay
```

```
RAID set "sil_ajajcfbibhah" was activated
RAID set "sil_ajajcfbibhah1" was activated
```

```
sudo blkid
```

gave me the UUID

```
/dev/mapper/sil_ajajcfbibhah1: UUID="59b2e940-380c-4087-bd6a-50e9cc23ccfc" TYPE="xfs"
```

After that I was able to add an entry to /etc/fstab

```
UUID=59b2e940-380c-4087-bd6a-50e9cc23ccfc /media/storage    xfs defualts  0 0
```

Hope this may help others.